# Any tool to automatically fix simple JSLint issues?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I've run JSLint for the first time on a rather lengthy file, and I have a lot of errors like `expected exactly 1 space between "function" and "("` or `unexpected ' '`. I didn't realize this was important at all anywhere I learned about javascript and now fixing each one of these rather simple things by hand seems frustrating. Some I can figure out with simple find and replaces, but I wondered if there's any tools online that will automatically make these changes for me since they seem to be pretty straightforward?

(I have `/*jslint white: false */` in my file, I develop in [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) and auto-format (except then I have to correct hanging jQuery chainings because it doesn't do it right), and my code still ends up with a huge number of things that jslint complains about as far as unexpected numbers of spaces.)

Comment: Why not click the "tolerate messy whitespace" checkbox button on the jslint page?

Comment: I actually tried that and it didn't seem to have an effect

Comment: From the [JSLint Instructions](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) for `white` as of 2012-02-20 CET: "`true` if strict whitespace rules should be ignored." So change `white: false` to `white: true` if you want to get less complaints by JSLint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damon, [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) is probably going to do everything you want wrt painless javascript code formatting. It will convert your code to an AST and then pretty print it back into your file so it auto-formats as you go. You can even add it as a precommit hook or run it on a folder full of files (pretty quickly, too!) so that your entire codebase will be immediately pretty.

[Here is a video from ReactConf that explains it pretty well](https://youtu.be/hkfBvpEfWdA)

Answer (score 17):

While it checks for different things than JSLint, the `fixjsstyle` mode of the [Google closure linter](http://code.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto.html) may do what you want.

It automatically fixes code to (more closely) fit with the [Google Javascript style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) which is well worth a read.

As others have pointed out, the [Javascript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) is the way to go for spacing issues.

Comment: I looked at that page and I was unsure about how to install/run it; it appears to need some type of PERL environment?

Comment: You'll need Python - the install for mac worked for me by running the line they suggest. What operating system do you have?

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the closure linter doesn't change `function() {}` -> `function () {}`. You could use regexes to clean those up - let me know if you'd like help. However, I'm very surprised that the beautifier didn't work for you - try running a subset of your code through it to find out what part makes it go crazy (it shouldn't look like that).

Comment: the beautifier is being really weird it turns `        } else if ($(this).val() && $('#elementSelectionList li a[href="#' + elementListing + '"]')
                .hasClass('logo')) {
            $('#elementSel` into `       } else if (!$(this).val() && $('#elementSelectionList li a[href="#' + elementListing + '"]').hasClass('logo'
        ogo ')) {
            $(') {$('#elementSel`  which is very hard to read but it's basically cutting off lines before they're finished and repeating a few chars+ the remainder on the next line. doesn't start til line 199 tho

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Try beautifying your code in two halves (as long as the halving is done at a legal place, parse-wise), or beautifying using the command line tool instead. If that doesn't work, file a bug [here](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify/issues).

Answer (score 11):

There's an npm module called [fixmyjs](https://github.com/jshint/fixmyjs).

In "legacy mode" with JSHint:

```
var jshint = require('jshint').JSHINT
    var fixmyjs = require('fixmyjs')
    jshint(stringOfCode, objectOfOptions)
    var stringFixedCode = fixmyjs(jshint.data(), stringOfCode, objectOfOptions).run()
```

Works great!

There is also a [Sublime Text 2/3 Package](https://github.com/addyosmani/sublime-fixmyjs).

Comment: Ugh, this is almost great – unfortunately --legacy mode no longer works and the default formatter strips all empty lines: https://github.com/jshint/fixmyjs/issues/88

Comment: Hello, author here, Legacy mode still works, all the tests are passing. Do you have a failing test case?

Answer (score 6):

http://jsbeautifier.org/  should fix all your problems

Comment: wow.. beautifier brutalizes my code: http://i.imgur.com/9H5Vb.jpg

Comment: yeah man. thats how it does. just like jslint/csslint will hurt your feelings. dont take it personal, the browsers sure don't.

Comment: i guess my idea of 'beauty' is a bit different? lol.. I'm just confused as to why it would do it that way.

Comment: @damon it was pretty ugly to begin with, though =/

Comment: voting this down, it is not going to fix tabs instead of spaces, braces in wrong columns etc PS. up again, just space betwin function() and parens wasnt fixed

Answer (score 4):

[jsfmt](https://github.com/rdio/jsfmt) formats javascript and allows AST searching and rewriting. Analogous to gofmt.

In some ide's like netbeans you can automatically format code with `alt+shift+f`.

There are also online ones. http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 3):

Simply use IDE which supports custom code formatting. Like NetBeans, WebStorm or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of tools around for doing things like this. I use [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) which will at least fix indentation errors and also the spaces-around-functions-part (I've tested it, yay!)

Answer (score 2):

If you use/have Visual Studio it does formatting of JavaScript too. You may need to configure formatting options from defaults.