# Is there a tool that can scan all my files and remove "trailing commas" for javascript?

Tags: javascript

As you know, trailing commas break IE.

Is there a tool that, given a directory, it can traverse all its subdirectories, and scan all *.js files....removing trailing commas from them?

Comment: Linux's egrep with regex

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

```
var x = {a: "", b: "", };
```

Results in:

```
Error:

Problem at line 1 character 22: Unexpected ','.

var x = {a: "", b: "", };
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't traverse directories and do the removal.  However, this leads to these answers, which may be helpful:

- [Any tool to automatically fix simple JSLint issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564139/any-tool-to-automatically-fix-simple-jslint-issues)
- [What is a good stand-alone JavaScript formatter for fixing missing semicolons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045241/what-is-a-good-stand-alone-javascript-formatter-for-fixing-missing-semicolons)